# Set a member of a C structure of type char * with Java byte array using SWIG

Tags: java, swig

For example we have the following structure:

```
typedef struct Foo
{
    unsigned char * data;
} Foo;
```

I want to set the `data` member with a Java byte array (`byte[]`). I only want set method not get. I've read the [getting of a member of type char * to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965992/convert-a-member-of-structure-of-type-signed-char-to-byte-array-in-java-byte), but I can't do the setting. Can anybody help me?

**UPDATED**:

I've created some type maps and I have a success:

```
%typemap(jni) unsigned char * data "jbyteArray"
%typemap(jtype) unsigned char * data "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) unsigned char * data "byte[]"
%typemap(javaout) unsigned char * data {
    return $jnicall;
}
%typemap(out) signed char * data {
    $result = JCALL1(NewByteArray, jenv, arg1->contentLength);
    JCALL4(SetByteArrayRegion, jenv, $result, 0, arg1->contentLength, $1);
}
%typemap(in) unsigned char *data {
    $1 = (unsigned char *)JCALL2(GetByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, 0);
}
%typemap(javain) unsigned char *data "$javainput"
```

Do I have some memory leaks? Have I made it wrong or is there more reliable way?

Comment: You've not got anything calling `RelaseByteArrayElements` ever. I think you probably want to do something using `memcpy` to copy the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Or we could do it with [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) instead. Something like this should work:

```
public static class Foo extends Pointer {
    static { Loader.load(); }
    public Foo() { allocate(); }
    public Foo(Pointer p) { super(p); }
    private native void allocate();

    public native @MemberSetter void data(@Cast("unsigned char*") BytePointer data);
}
```

That is IMO much more readable.